# page turning animation

Tags: vb.net

I am building an application.  This shows a form, header and footer are to be kept fixed.
In the middle there is a Group Box that hold a question with different option.
When user clicks Next button at the bottom, Group Box loads next question.
I want to make this change animated.  I wish to show a page-turning animation that runs when Next button is clicked...................

Please help
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: What technology are using?  WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nicely written tutorial for **[doing this in C# and GDI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/TurnThePage.aspx)** but it's fairly complicated.

There is also a simpler tutorial, also on CodeProject, for **[doing this with Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/PageFlipNavigation.aspx)**.

Comment: But Can I use that in vb.net?

Comment: If you want to use the C# example you'll need to translate it to VB.NET.  What technology are you using? Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows forms but I
reaaly donor know how to translate 
C# example in VB.net
can u help?

Comment: @user415037: If the tutorial is in C#, then there's a 95% chance it can be done in VB.NET. Here's a free online tool to do the conversion for you: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/  I stand to be corrected but as of VS2010 the only major C# feature that's absent in VB.NET is unmanaged code.

Comment: I tried the link it converts the code only but I need to convert the whole project.  Is it possible?
Thanks and best regards,
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Loading screen in VB.Net

To create a loading screen you need to understand the ‘BackgroundWorker’ which is part of the Imports System.ComponentModel

1. Create a Loading form with your loading message and picture. This form will act as a popup form
2. I called my form ‘frmPleaseWait’ and placed the following code in it

Public Class frmPleaseWait

```
Private _worker As BackgroundWorker

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    _worker = New BackgroundWorker()
    AddHandler _worker.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    AddHandler _worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    'your loading animation code goes here
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

1. In your main form in between the code that’s taking the processing time place

> ```
> Dim frm As New frmPleaseWait
> frm.ShowDialog()
> 'your time consuming main processing code goes here
> frm.Close()
> ```

1. That’s all, if you want to make the popup form appear longer then change the threading time in WorkerDoWork method.

@Furqan, in your case, in this section you need to put your animation code in the WorkerDoWork method

Dont forget to use `Imports System.ComponentModel` at the top of the loading form class

Thanks Eddy Jawed